# What addresses do the pointer store?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

I am currently in the learning process of pointers in C.
I came to know that, a pointer is a variable which stores the address of another variable.
So when I did something like,

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &x;
    printf("%d" ,ptr);
```

The above gave me the address in integer values.
My question is, the pointer variable ptr stores address of variable of type int.
As per my PC, int is taking 4 bytes which is 32 bits. As per my understanding each bit has a separate memory address.

So what is the address pointer will point to? Will it point to the first bits memory address or something else? Please let me know.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: "each bit has a separate memory address" - no, that is not the case on virtually any CPU architecture

Comment: okay. so do you mean memory addresses are group of bytes?

Comment: Do you know the difference of bit and byte?

Comment: (8-bit) bytes on most general purpose CPUs today

Comment: Think of it like this. The memory location tells you how far down the road a vehicle is parked. That vehicle may be a motorbike, a car or a lorry truck. It is dependent of the size of an object to understand how much space the vehicle takes. And the direction the vehicle is parked in, depends on endianness.

Comment: @Mat `no, that is not the case on virtually any CPU architecture` . You are wrong . For example zilions of Cortex-M uCs have "bit banding" areas where every single bit of this area has its own memory address.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h78DyF1NOio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A memory address is the location of one byte. A 32-bit location is the location on a four byte boundary.

So memory address 0x0000 is equal to the first 32-bit memory location. Address 0x0004 would be equal to the next four-byte boundary or, in other words, the next 32-bit location.

Then that just leaves the issue of [big-endian and little-endian](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/).

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah, I see what you mean. Edited it.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for your comments. So by this I came to know that, each bit does not have a memory address, instead each byte has an address. But this still doesn't answer my question. Say I have an integer variable and it has 4 bytes and a pointer is referencing to this integer variable. So which memory address(meaning which bytes address among the 4 bytes) will be used by the pointer

Comment: @nano If your variable is a 32-bit declaration, then it will point to the first byte of that memory location.

Comment: @Rob Depending on what you mean with "first" it can be depending on big or small endian

Comment: @klutt Yes. In fact, I'll point to an excellent article about all this: https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/ until I find the time to edit my answer to include that discussion.

Comment: @Rob I have understood that, the pointer will be referring to the first address of the boundary. But how does it know where to stop(I mean the last boundary), based on the type of variable? I gues?

Answer (score 2):

On systems like x86, each individual byte has its own address.  For multi-byte objects like `int`s or `double`s, the address of the object is the address of its *first* byte.  On a little-endian system like x86, the first byte is the least-significant byte, while on a big-endian system like Power the first byte is the most significant byte:

```
int x = 0x01234567;

 A      A+1    A+2    A+3      big-endian
+––––––+––––––+––––––+––––––+
| 0x01 | 0x23 | 0x45 | 0x67 |
+––––––+––––––+––––––+––––––+
 A+3    A+2    A+1    A        little-endian
```

Most architectures have alignment restrictions such that multi-byte entities must have an address that is a multiple of 2 or 4.  This is why `struct` types may have "padding" bytes between members.

Addressing and byte ordering are a function of the underlying architecture, not the C language.  There are some word-addressed systems where each individual byte does *not* have its own address, so pointers to smaller types like `char` may need to include an offset into the word. Representation of pointer types can vary.

Unless you’re working on bare metal, the address values you’re working with are virtual addresses, not physical.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding each bit has a separate memory address.

No, every *byte* has a memory address. You'll have to use an additional offset to get individual bits. You cannot make a pointer point at a single bit.

> So what is the address pointer will point to? Will it point to the first bits memory address or something else? Please let me know.

Nope. It points to the *object* as a whole. You cannot say which byte in the object, because that depends on endianness.

Furthermore, when compiled with `-Wall -Wextra` this gives a warning.

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

You're using the wrong format specifier for printing a pointer. `%d` is for `int`. Your pointer, however, has the type `int*` which is not `int`. If you want to print the address, use this instead:

```
printf("%p", (void*)ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimum addressable unit is byte. Independent on how much bytes an object of the type `int` occupies a pointer to such an object points to the first byte of the extent of memory occupied by the object.

From the C Standard

> **3.5**
> **1 bit**
>
> unit of data storage in the execution environment large enough to hold
> an object that may have one of two values
>
> 2 NOTE It need not be possible to express the address of each
> individual bit of an object.
>
> **3.6**
> **1 byte**
> addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of
> the basic character set of the execution environment

Pay attention to that this call

```
printf("%d" ,ptr);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

If you want to output the value of a pointer you should use the conversion specifier `p`. For example

```
printf("%p\n" , ( void * )ptr);
```

Comment: Some processors allow 1 bit addressing. For example Cortex M have bitband areas . `Bit banding is a feature of ARM Cortex-M processors that maps up-to 1Mb each of on-chip SRAM and peripheral registers to a larger region where each 32 bit address corresponds to a single bit of the physical memory.  Setting the bitband address to zero or non-zero directly and atomically sets the corresponding physical memory bit to zero or one respectively, without the need for read-modify-write operations or critical sections.`

Comment: @ – 0___________ In fact this is not in accordance with the C Standard.